# Can I say “what was the war a reaction to?”

Tags: meaning, usage

If I mean to ask the main causes of something, so I want to know what something reacted to, can I say “what was the war a reaction to?”? It sounds pretty weird to me... I’d rather say “what did the war react to?” Are they both right? Are they both wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is incorrect, but in my opinion both are awkward.

> what did the war react to?

Implies that the war is like a living thing which can react to other things, which it isn';t, unless you are intending to personify "war" or "the war".

Simpler and more straightforward woudl be

> What were the major causes of the war?

or

> What factors contributed to the outbreak of the war?

One could use "consequence" instead of reaction, as in:

> What was the war a consequence of?

But I still think this a bit more awkward.

One should remember that a war pretty much always has multiple causes and use a form which permits multiple answers. I recall a historical writer saying:

> Whenever I here someone say "**The** cause of the Roman Civil War was..." I know he doesn't know enough about the subject to be worth listening to.

Comment: I used “the war” as an example.  I as well find both forms awkward since it seems they have been translated from Italian word for word... thanks